# Xephyr and xorg process

Tags: x11, xorg, x-server, xephyr

I run Xephyr:`Xephyr -ac -screen 1024x768 -br -reset -terminate 2> /dev/null :1 &` and then I can run there some window:

```
export DISPLAY=:1
xterm &
```

When I check xorg processes `ps ax | grep xorg` I only see one xorg process but Xephyr also runs Xserver so why it is not visible ?

Comment: `ps ax | grep xorg` will match the command line like `/usr/lib/xorg/Xorg :0 ....`. What makes you believe that the command line you are running (`Xephyr -ac ...`) should match `xorg` despite not containing the `xorg` string anywhere?

Comment: I have thought that Xephyr runs a host xorg imeplementation but it looks like the Xephyr implements server protocol internally.

Comment: Xorg and Xephyr share most of their code and are built from the same source, but `ps ax` will still print just the command line (the same thing you can get with`tr '\0' ' ' </proc/PID/cmdline` on linux).

Comment: Actually, you can replace Xvfb (the "dumb framebuffer" Xserver) with stock Xorg + xf86-video-dummy driver, but I don't think if you can do the same with Xorg + xf86-video-nested on a stock distro. Example for xf86-video-dummy: `echo 'Section "Device" Identifier "dummy" Driver "dummy" EndSection' | PATH=/usr/lib/xorg:$PATH Xorg -config /dev/stdin :3`